# Deploying a Django application with Apache on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: django, apache, mod-wsgi, django-wsgi

I have been striking my head against an application to be deployed on an Apache server using Ubuntu 16.04. I thought may be it's a misconfiguration issue in my site, so just deployed a test app `test_app` and following the very basic instructions on [Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/howto/deployment/wsgi/modwsgi/) and here's what I inserted in my `/etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf`:

```
WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/html/python/test_app/test_app/wsgi.py

#WSGIPythonHome /var/www/html/python/test_app/venv
#WSGIPythonPath /var/www/html/python/test_app

Alias /static/ /var/www/html/python/test_app/static/

<Directory /var/www/html/python/test_app/static>
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
Require all granted
</Directory>


<Directory /var/www/html/python/test_app/test_app>
<Files wsgi.py>
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
Require all granted
</Files>
</Directory>
```

And, I can't see anything on `localhost`. Am I doing configurations right?

Here are the errors generated in the log:

```
[Mon Mar 20 14:19:16.518151 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 12272:tid 140248747980544] [client 127.0.0.1:50998] mod_wsgi (pid=12272): Target WSGI script '/var/www/html/python/test_app/test_app/wsgi.py' cannot be loaded as Python module.
[Mon Mar 20 14:19:16.518215 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 12272:tid 140248747980544] [client 127.0.0.1:50998] mod_wsgi (pid=12272): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/var/www/html/python/test_app/test_app/wsgi.py'.
[Mon Mar 20 14:19:16.518241 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 12272:tid 140248747980544] [client 127.0.0.1:50998] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Mon Mar 20 14:19:16.518278 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 12272:tid 140248747980544] [client 127.0.0.1:50998]   File "/var/www/html/python/test_app/test_app/wsgi.py", line 17, in <module>
[Mon Mar 20 14:19:16.518351 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 12272:tid 140248747980544] [client 127.0.0.1:50998]     application = get_wsgi_application()
[Mon Mar 20 14:19:16.518366 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 12272:tid 140248747980544] [client 127.0.0.1:50998]   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/wsgi.py", line 13, in get_wsgi_application
[Mon Mar 20 14:19:16.518406 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 12272:tid 140248747980544] [client 127.0.0.1:50998]     django.setup(set_prefix=False)
[Mon Mar 20 14:19:16.518421 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 12272:tid 140248747980544] [client 127.0.0.1:50998]   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/__init__.py", line 22, in setup
[Mon Mar 20 14:19:16.518462 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 12272:tid 140248747980544] [client 127.0.0.1:50998]     configure_logging(settings.LOGGING_CONFIG, settings.LOGGING)
[Mon Mar 20 14:19:16.518476 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 12272:tid 140248747980544] [client 127.0.0.1:50998]   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 53, in __getattr__
[Mon Mar 20 14:19:16.518571 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 12272:tid 140248747980544] [client 127.0.0.1:50998]     self._setup(name)
[Mon Mar 20 14:19:16.518586 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 12272:tid 140248747980544] [client 127.0.0.1:50998]   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 41, in _setup
[Mon Mar 20 14:19:16.518605 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 12272:tid 140248747980544] [client 127.0.0.1:50998]     self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
[Mon Mar 20 14:19:16.518618 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 12272:tid 140248747980544] [client 127.0.0.1:50998]   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 97, in __init__
[Mon Mar 20 14:19:16.518634 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 12272:tid 140248747980544] [client 127.0.0.1:50998]     mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)
[Mon Mar 20 14:19:16.518648 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 12272:tid 140248747980544] [client 127.0.0.1:50998]   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
[Mon Mar 20 14:19:16.518694 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 12272:tid 140248747980544] [client 127.0.0.1:50998]     __import__(name)
[Mon Mar 20 14:19:16.518719 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 12272:tid 140248747980544] [client 127.0.0.1:50998] ImportError: No module named test_app.settings
```

Comment: Have you tried with a WSGI hello world application, rather than Django? http://modwsgi.readthedocs.io/en/develop/user-guides/quick-configuration-guide.html

Comment: @GrahamDumpleton looks like I have to try that first.

Comment: @FaizanAli Above `Require all granted`, add this line - `Order deny,allow`. See if it works.

Comment: Unbuntu 16.04 should be Apache 2.4 I would think, which means ``Require all granted`` should be fine. The older Apache 2.2 ways of things will not work with Apache 2.4 unless the access compat module is enabled.

Comment: Okay, I have followed basic hello world as suggested by @GrahamDumpleton , that works fine. But, when trying Django, it doesn't work. I'm pasting my apache error log in the question edit.

Answer (score 0):

So, finally.. I figured it out! Thanks for your help guys.

As my first line in the error log says:

`'/var/www/html/python/test_app/test_app/wsgi.py' cannot be loaded as Python module.`

that means `wsgi.py` was not accessible to the Apache Module. I searched for it over here and got the [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32577998/wsgi-script-cannot-be-loaded-as-python-module-500-internal-server-error).

So, in my `wsgi.py`, I added this:

```
import os, sys
from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
sys.path.append('/var/www/html/python/test_app')
```

and it worked.

Comment: Would recommend you read http://modwsgi.readthedocs.io/en/develop/user-guides/virtual-environments.html Use daemon mode, and set up Python virtual environment using ``python-home`` and location of your project using ``python-path``.

Answer (score 0):

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName programmerlab.com # this ll be your domain name
  WSGIDaemonProcess programmerlab.com python-path=/var/www/html/gautam.tech:/var/www/html/programmerlab.com/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages
  WSGIProcessGroup programmerlab.com

  #Your static files location
        Alias /static /var/www/html/programmerlab.com/portfolio/static
        <Directory /var/www/html/programmerlab.com/portfolio/static>
            Require all granted
        </Directory>

    <LocationMatch "\.(jpg|gif|png|js|css)$">
        SetHandler None
    </LocationMatch>

 WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/html/programmerlab.com/myproject/wsgi.py
 DocumentRoot /var/www/html/programmerlab.com
    <Directory /var/www/html/programmerlab.com/myproject>
        <Files wsgi.py>
        Require all granted
        </Files>
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

to know about python path just type

> which python

at the terminal.

This vhost setting is fully tested and this ll work for sure.