# Django and mod_wsgi installation suddenly stopped working

Tags: django, mod-wsgi, apt-get

I have a script which I use to install my application on a virtual machine using `django 1.9.6` and `mod_wsgi`. It use to work fine for at least a year and then after a few months I didn't use it - it's suddenly not working. I am always installing on a clean ubuntu trusty image and I didn't make any changes. So my guess is that `apt-get` is installing a different version of `libapache2-mod-wsgi` now.

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y python-pip
sudo pip install django=1.9.6
sudo pip install python-social-auth
sudo apt-get -y install apache2 libapache2-mod-wsgi
...
```

When I try to run the application the apache server gives the error:

```
[Tue Oct 17 11:52:29.184072 2017] [:error] [pid 8178:tid 140000402241280] [remote 131.111.64.116:33385] mod_wsgi (pid=8178): Target WSGI script '/root/geosearch_app/geosearch_project/geosearch_project/wsgi.py' cannot be loaded as Python module.
[Tue Oct 17 11:52:29.184116 2017] [:error] [pid 8178:tid 140000402241280] [remote 131.111.64.116:33385] mod_wsgi (pid=8178): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/root/geosearch_app/geosearch_project/geosearch_project/wsgi.py'.
[Tue Oct 17 11:52:29.184140 2017] [:error] [pid 8178:tid 140000402241280] [remote 131.111.64.116:33385] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Tue Oct 17 11:52:29.184159 2017] [:error] [pid 8178:tid 140000402241280] [remote 131.111.64.116:33385]   File "/root/geosearch_app/geosearch_project/geosearch_project/wsgi.py", line 16, in <module>
[Tue Oct 17 11:52:29.184212 2017] [:error] [pid 8178:tid 140000402241280] [remote 131.111.64.116:33385]     application = get_wsgi_application()
[Tue Oct 17 11:52:29.184225 2017] [:error] [pid 8178:tid 140000402241280] [remote 131.111.64.116:33385]   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/wsgi.py", line 13, in get_wsgi_application
[Tue Oct 17 11:52:29.184266 2017] [:error] [pid 8178:tid 140000402241280] [remote 131.111.64.116:33385]     django.setup()
[Tue Oct 17 11:52:29.184280 2017] [:error] [pid 8178:tid 140000402241280] [remote 131.111.64.116:33385]   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/__init__.py", line 18, in setup
[Tue Oct 17 11:52:29.184327 2017] [:error] [pid 8178:tid 140000402241280] [remote 131.111.64.116:33385]     apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
[Tue Oct 17 11:52:29.184339 2017] [:error] [pid 8178:tid 140000402241280] [remote 131.111.64.116:33385]   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 108, in populate
[Tue Oct 17 11:52:29.184458 2017] [:error] [pid 8178:tid 140000402241280] [remote 131.111.64.116:33385]     app_config.import_models(all_models)
[Tue Oct 17 11:52:29.184471 2017] [:error] [pid 8178:tid 140000402241280] [remote 131.111.64.116:33385]   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 202, in import_models
[Tue Oct 17 11:52:29.184549 2017] [:error] [pid 8178:tid 140000402241280] [remote 131.111.64.116:33385]     self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
[Tue Oct 17 11:52:29.184561 2017] [:error] [pid 8178:tid 140000402241280] [remote 131.111.64.116:33385]   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
[Tue Oct 17 11:52:29.184738 2017] [:error] [pid 8178:tid 140000402241280] [remote 131.111.64.116:33385]     __import__(name)
[Tue Oct 17 11:52:29.184751 2017] [:error] [pid 8178:tid 140000402241280] [remote 131.111.64.116:33385]   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/social/apps/django_app/default/models.py", line 1, in <module>
[Tue Oct 17 11:52:29.184791 2017] [:error] [pid 8178:tid 140000402241280] [remote 131.111.64.116:33385]     from social_django.models import AbstractUserSocialAuth, UserSocialAuth, Nonce, Association, Code, DjangoStorage
[Tue Oct 17 11:52:29.184819 2017] [:error] [pid 8178:tid 140000402241280] [remote 131.111.64.116:33385] ImportError: No module named social_django.models
[Tue Oct 17 11:52:29.289697 2017] [:error] [pid 8178:tid 140000419026688] [remote 131.111.64.116:24169] mod_wsgi (pid=8178): Target WSGI script '/root/geosearch_app/geosearch_project/geosearch_project/wsgi.py' cannot be loaded as Python module.
[Tue Oct 17 11:52:29.289725 2017] [:error] [pid 8178:tid 140000419026688] [remote 131.111.64.116:24169] mod_wsgi (pid=8178): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/root/geosearch_app/geosearch_project/geosearch_project/wsgi.py'.
[Tue Oct 17 11:52:29.289745 2017] [:error] [pid 8178:tid 140000419026688] [remote 131.111.64.116:24169] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Tue Oct 17 11:52:29.289768 2017] [:error] [pid 8178:tid 140000419026688] [remote 131.111.64.116:24169]   File "/root/geosearch_app/geosearch_project/geosearch_project/wsgi.py", line 16, in <module>
[Tue Oct 17 11:52:29.289799 2017] [:error] [pid 8178:tid 140000419026688] [remote 131.111.64.116:24169]     application = get_wsgi_application()
[Tue Oct 17 11:52:29.289809 2017] [:error] [pid 8178:tid 140000419026688] [remote 131.111.64.116:24169]   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/wsgi.py", line 13, in get_wsgi_application
[Tue Oct 17 11:52:29.289827 2017] [:error] [pid 8178:tid 140000419026688] [remote 131.111.64.116:24169]     django.setup()
[Tue Oct 17 11:52:29.289836 2017] [:error] [pid 8178:tid 140000419026688] [remote 131.111.64.116:24169]   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/__init__.py", line 18, in setup
[Tue Oct 17 11:52:29.289850 2017] [:error] [pid 8178:tid 140000419026688] [remote 131.111.64.116:24169]     apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
[Tue Oct 17 11:52:29.289859 2017] [:error] [pid 8178:tid 140000419026688] [remote 131.111.64.116:24169]   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 78, in populate
[Tue Oct 17 11:52:29.289873 2017] [:error] [pid 8178:tid 140000419026688] [remote 131.111.64.116:24169]     raise RuntimeError("populate() isn't reentrant")
[Tue Oct 17 11:52:29.289891 2017] [:error] [pid 8178:tid 140000419026688] [remote 131.111.64.116:24169] RuntimeError: populate() isn't reentrant
```

I hope to solve this without actually changing anything except the installation script and that should work since it worked before.

Any advice?

Comment: Make sure there is an `__init__.py` file in the directory where there `wsgi.py` lies. ie `cd /path/to/wsgi.py && touch __init__.py`

Comment: It's there. As I said, it all worked a while ago and I didn't change anything

Comment: I see three dots in the error you provide. Why is that? `target WSGI script '/.../wsgi.py'`. This is not at all normal.

Comment: I just replaced the path to my wsgi.py with dots

Comment: Are you using a virtualenv? Check this [anwer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32579434/2996101) to make sure that the path to your wsgi is in your python path.

Comment: What are the rest of error messages in the Apache error log? The line you quote is only the first and is usually always followed by a Python traceback and exception.

Comment: @GrahamDumpleton, I added it. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See:

- https://github.com/omab/python-social-auth/issues/1073

It looks like you have installed a newer version of the package which has different requirements for setup and requires extra packages to be installed.

You may want to pin the package to the same older version you were previously using as there may be other changes you might have to make to your code and database otherwise.

Comment: Thanks! `sudo pip install python-social-auth==0.2.21` did it