# WSGI script cannot be loaded as Python Module

Tags: django, apache2, mod-wsgi

I have been trying to troubleshoot an internal server error I've been getting from my local install of django 2.0.2 whlist trying to run it in a python 3.6.3 virtualenv on apache 2.4.27 via mod-wsgi-py3 4.5.17 running in Daemon mode.

**Update:**

> I have solved the problems and there are no additional errors remaining.  The initial problem was solved by the simple addition of python-home and python-path arguments to the WSGIDaemonProcess directive.  The second problem turned out to be caused by me not having configured static files, which I have since corrected by reading the django docs on the topic of static files.  Thus I am no longer in need of help with these problems and we can mark this as solved
>
> I have since done additional troubleshooting and was able to progress past the internal server error 500 to a new error of **ImproperlyConfigured at /** by changing the WSGIDaemonProcess line in wurst.conf to

`WSGIDaemonProcess wurst processes=2 threads=15 python-home=/home/mike/blog-env python-path=/home/mike/blog-env/wurstblog

> <s>Technicaly</s> I have solved my initial problem <s>but presented a new one.</s>

**EndUpdate**
`

In my apache2 error.log file, I can see

`[Thu Feb 08 10:34:24.694864 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 94364] [remote 127.0.0.1:47002] mod_wsgi (pid=94364): Target WSGI script '/var/www/wsgi-scripts/wurstblog.wsgi' cannot be loaded as Python module.`

Searching the internet far and wide I have found various potential solutions that include
[WSGI Script Cannot Be Loaded as Python Module -- 500 Internal Server Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32577998/wsgi-script-cannot-be-loaded-as-python-module-500-internal-server-error)

```
'How python is installed'
'Missmatch of mod-wsgi and python environment version'
'conflict with mod_python and mod_wsgi'
```

I am not sure how to correct any problem with my python3 installation, nor that of mod_python

I read somewhere that the wsgi script needed to be executable so `ls -l /var/www/wsgi-scripts` gives
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 454 Feb  8 10:52 wurstblog.wsgi

it looks like this:

```
import os
import sys

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
sys.path.append('/home/mike/blog-env/wurstblog/wurstblog')
os.environ["DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE"] = "wurstblog.settings"

application = get_wsgi_application()
```

blog-env is my pthon3 virtualenv and wurstblog is where my django project is
I have configured a virtualhost /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/wurst.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

    ServerAdmin myname@nospam.com
    <Directory /var/www/wsgi-scripts>
        <Files wurstblog.wsgi>
        Require all granted
        </Files>
    </Directory>

</VirtualHost>

    WSGIPythonHome /home/mike/blog-env
    WSGIPythonPath /home/mike/blog-env/wurstblog
    WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/wsgi-scripts/wurstblog.wsgi 
    WSGIDaemonProcess wurst processes=2 threads=15
    WSGIProcessGroup wurst
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined


# vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet
```

Does anyone have any suggestions on what I can try to correct this problem, thank you.

Comment: The ``cannot be loaded as Python module`` error should be followed by a Python stack trace and exception. You need to provide that information or it is impossible to guess what the problem is.

Comment: Thank you Graham, I did not think to include this and will do so in the future.  For now, however, it seems I have completely solved my problem.  See newest updates.

Comment: BTW, if this is the only WSGI application you are running, add the directive ``WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}``. This avoids issues with some Python modules that don't work in sub interpreters. Also since using daemon mode, a good idea to completely disable embedded mode by adding ``WSGIRestrictEmbedded On``. The latter must be outside of the ``VirtualHost``.

Comment: Thank you Graham I will probably be running multiple Django sites as I learn.  Would setting the WSGIApplicationGroup have any effect on preventing me from say creating other sites.  I like the idea of disabling embedded mode and will have to keep that in mind as I progress forward with my endavours to learn Django.  I much apreciate your guidance.

Comment: You should use a separate daemon process group for each Django site instance anyway.